# Django hosting with mod_wsgi / apache with Python2.7 and Python3 concurrently

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a Django website hosted with apache/mod_wsgi. The site has originally been written in Python2.7, but I am now in the process of changing over to Python3.

I have a QA version of site available for external testing, and I would like to run that site on Python3 - while the main production site stays on Python2.7 for some time.

The sites are currently served with two different `<virtualhost>` settings.

```
<virtualhost>
...
WSGIDaemonProcess name processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
...
</virtualhost>
```

This works. However - when trying to use Python3 I have compiled (`pip install`) a new version of `mod_wsgi` against Python3 development environment, however from apache there is a conflict - I can only have one version of the `mod_wsgi` module loaded.

Is it at all possible to run Python2.7 and Python3 based `mod_wsgi` modules concurrently in the same Apache instance? Or is this the time to really change the hosting configuration (multiple Apache instances??) or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use 2 different Apache instances.

According to this [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/599859/multiple-python-versions-under-apachemod-wsgi#comment816528_599864) from the creator of mod_wsgi:

> It is an operating system limitation. You can't load two different versions of the Python library into the one process. – Graham Dumpleton

That said, if your whole purpose is to switch from Python2 to Python3, why would you try to run both simultaneously on a single process? Shouldn't you just try testing if switching everything to Python 3 works?